# Parameter sniffing issue with RECOMPILE on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure created with the RECOMPILE- flag:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ABC].[ProcedureName]    
( @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(255), @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME, @Parameter4 NVARCHAR(255)
    , @Parameter5 NVARCHAR(255), @Parameter5 NVARCHAR(255)    
)
WITH RECOMPILE
```

This procedure creates a table-valued parameter used to match the required rows and then uses those on queries to 6 different tables, joined by an union:

```
DECLARE @TVP TABLE    
(ID BIGINT, ValB NVARCHAR(18), ValC NVARCHAR(10))    

INSERT INTO @TVP    
SELECT ... 
INNER JOIN ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
WHERE ... AND ...   AND ...

    -- Query 1 
SELECT @Parameter1 as Col1,
TableA.Col2 as Col2, 
...
FROM [ABC].[TableA] TableA    
INNER JOIN @TVP TVP ON TVP.ID = TableA.ID    
WHERE @StartTime <= TableA.ENDTIME AND @EndTime >= TableA.STARTTIME

UNION ALL

-- Query 2   
SELECT  @Parameter1 as Col1,
TableB.Col2 as Col2, 
...
FROM [ABC].[TableB] TableB    
INNER JOIN @TVP TVP ON TVP.ID = TableB.ID    
WHERE @StartTime <= TableB.ENDTIME AND @EndTime >= TableB.STARTTIME

UNION ALL

...

-- Query 3 - 6

ORDER BY Col2
```

The tables used in the query have a very different range of number of rows, most have 0 to 2 entries, but one table has a huge number of rows, up to 100 millions and beyond. The expected number of returned rows for a normal use of the SP is between 1 and 500 rows. The input parameters `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` used in every query are user-selected times.

Now, to my understanding, the use of those parameters makes this procedure a possible 'victim' of parameter sniffing, so the SP is created with the `RECOMPILE` hint. But this does not the affect the execution time of the statement at all. Instead, when using local variables instead of those used when calling the procedure (e.g. using `@LocalStartTime` in the query instead of `@StartTime`), the execution time is reduced drastically, from multiple minutes to a few seconds. The query plans are showing big differences between the estimated and actual number of rows ([slow case: 19184600 estimated / 531075 actual], [   acceptable case: 45186 estimated / 100 actual])

[Slow execution plan]
[image: Slow execution plan]

[Better execution plan]
[image: Better execution plan]

Could someone explain to me why even with the `RECOMPILE` hint parameter sniffing seems to be an issue? Also, is there a chance to bring the estimation even closer to the actual rows?

Comment: Your procedure creates a table variable, not a TVP. This doesn't affect the code, of course, but calling it a TVP is confusing.

Comment: What happens if you put an OPTION recompile at the end of your SELECT .... UNION ...

Comment: SQL Server doesn't maintain statistics for table variables. What happens if you use temp tables instead?

Comment: following @JeroenMostert suggestion why not use a CTE and then JOIN to that in your SELECT statements

Comment: I've replaced the table variable with a temp table while using the passed parameters directly, and it actually runs as fast as the procedure with the local parameters and uses a similar execution plan. The estimated # of rows is even closer now to the actual with 10104 est. rows. The name @TVP slipped through when making this post, the actual variable is of course named differently. Unfortunately I can't change that now, as I've also used it already in the screenshots.

Comment: I should also add that the table variable usually contains only 1 entry, and I've not seen an execution of the sp with more than 1 entry yet

Comment: I would create two or more sprocs to do the job. One sproc would be for short period and another would be for long period. Then I would pass the "correct" sproc depending on the range of the parameters.